# Output of Unet multi-class segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

#### I have several questions concerning a multi class image segmentation model pipeline.

##### 1 - Influence of images masks

I have created masks for each image according to this template :

1. (0,0,0) is the background,
2. (1,1,1) external wound,
3. (2,2,2) wound itself.

[Segmentation mask example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYx2M.jpg)
This example show the repartition of the wound and external wounds on the image but does not respect the (0,0,0)...etc template.

If I train a model respecting this template or using another template like :

1. (50,50,50) is the background,
2. (100,100,100) external wound,
3. (232,232,232) wound itself.

Does that influence the model. If I rescale `data = dict(rescale=1./255.)` my image does it still influence ?

##### 2 - Output of segmentation

[Output of image segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxdsg.png) The output of my model after training if really bad. What is the reason ?

This is the general pipeline of my model :

```
data_full_aug = dict(rescale=1./255.,
                     rotation_range=90,
                     vertical_flip=True,
                     horizontal_flip=True,
                     width_shift_range=0.3,
                     height_shift_range=0.3,
                     zoom_range=0.3,
                     shear_range=0.3, 
                     fill_mode = 'reflect'
                    )
```

The step below is repeated for the masks.

```
datagen_full_data_aug = ImageDataGenerator(**data_full_aug)

train_generator_images=datagen_full_data_aug.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train,
    directory=folder_images,
    x_col='filename',
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=True,
    seed = seed,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size))

validation_generator_images=datagen_no_data_aug.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=validation,
    directory=folder_images,
    x_col='filename',
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=True,
    seed = seed,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    target_size=(image_size,image_size))
```

Images and masks are then zipped.

```
train_generator = zip(train_generator_images, train_generator_masks)
validation_generator = zip(validation_generator_images, validation_generator_masks)
```

And then the model fit.

```
history=model.fit(train_generator,
                  steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                  epochs=EPOCHS,
                  verbose=2,
                  validation_data=validation_generator,
                  validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch,
                  callbacks=[checkpoint],
                  batch_size = batch_size)
```

The model itself is taken from the library : segmentation-models. https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models

```
model = sm.Unet(input_shape=(image_size, image_size, nb_channels), 
                classes=nb_classes, 
                activation='softmax', 
                encoder_weights='imagenet')
```

I have tried changing the learning_rate and epochs values.

Comment: Your augmentation parameters are pretty strong, and you also have a lot of them. Try to tune them down a bit. Also beware that `ImageDataGenerator` is deprecated.

Comment: Why would the data augmentation parameters be considered pretty strong in my case ?

Comment: The values for most of the augmentations are bigger than usual. `rotation_range=90` or `shear_range=0.3` are examples for that. Usually the values are smaller to not skew the image too much into randomness (`shear_range` between 0.1 and 0.2 for example). Also, the more different parameters you combine, the heavier is the image augmented, as every augmentation is combined with the rest (for every augmentation there is a small chance that it is not applied). This could lead to heavily distorted images that are not much use for learning anymore. But this is just a guess.

Comment: You could also take a look at augmentation examples for other datasets to get a general feeling how much and what augmentation is used. And remember that not every augmentation makes sense for every dataset. For example, if you would seldom see an upside down  plane, you wouldn't want to use `vertical_flip` for the training set of planes.